# MVC3: delete an object in an database from an array of selected objects

Tags: entity-framework, nbuilder

I've successfully selected the Objects I want to delete. But the problem is when I remove an item from Object array, it doesn't make any changes. My code is following below..

My database

```
public List<Product> db = new ProductRepository().GetProducts();
```

Here it shows all the products with checkbox..

```
public ActionResult MultipleDeletes()
        {
            return View(db);
        }
```

On Submitting "Button named Delete", I got problem.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult MultipleDeletes(int[] selectedProducts)
        {  
            var del_products  = from x in selectedProducts
                           from y in db
                           where y.ProductId == x
                           select y;

            foreach (var item in del_products)
            {
                //Product p = db.Find(item.ProductId);
                //db.Remove(p);
                //db.SaveChanges();
            }                    

            return View(db);
        }
```

Could anyone help me?
can you also tell me, how to write Lambda expression instead of LinQ?

Comment: This question isnt actually about MVC its about your ERM framework. Which database access technology are you using?

Comment: Thats your actual database file, how are you accessing the database? are you using entity framework or linq to SQL or some other ORM?

Comment: I'm using Entity Framework (Model First).. I've got 2 model. Product Model, it's the attributes. and ProductRepository creates products using NBuilder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the model. I used NBuilder.. so it didn't really save the data.
I built an DbContext. Then it worked.
Solution is ..

```
public ProductDBContext db = new ProductDBContext();


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult MultipleDeletes(int[] selectedProducts)
        {
            foreach (int item in selectedProducts)
            {
               Product product = db.Where(p => p.ProductId == item).SingleOrDefault();
               db.Remove(product);
               db.SaveChanges();
            }
          return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you need to make use of Delete rather than remove.

Use following and see if it works

```
db.DeleteObject(p)
db.SaveChanges()
```

Comment: I already have from in the previous line. Product p = db.Find(item.ProductId).. it say that find has some invalid arguments. And then .DeleteObject doesn't appear in Intellisense.